# How do I do I make something loop 12 times using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I'm making a view that shows the agenda for 12 people all on the same page. So, rather than individually coding 12 agendas with FullCalendar, how would I create a loop that runs 12 times and makes the 12 agendas?

This is how I want the format to be:

```
avail1.fullCalendar({
 header: {
  left: false,
  center: false,
  right: false,
 },

 height: 730,
 slotMinutes: 30,
 allDaySlot: false,
 minTime: 6,
 maxTime: '21:30',

 defaultView: 'agendaDay',
});
```

This renders the agenda for the first person but I want it to do this 11 more times. All I want is for the loop to change the #1 in line 1: `avail1.fullCalendar({` to change to 2, 3, 4, and all the way to 12.

If you need to see any more code just tell me thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it: (ERB template engine)

```
<% 12.times do |i| %>
  avail<%= i+1 %>.fullCalendar({
   header: {
    left: false,
    center: false,
    right: false,
   },

   height: 730,
   slotMinutes: 30,
   allDaySlot: false,
   minTime: 6,
   maxTime: '21:30',

   defaultView: 'agendaDay',
  });
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response but this isn't working for me. It's probably because I don't know how to embed Ruby into a js file, how would I loop in javascript?

Comment: @Snubber You should not use JS to loop through it. You should use a generic html class ".has_full_calendar" and use it to deploy full_calendar. I can update my answer with an example if you want